# passing php array to javascript using json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

This is the php script :

```
<?php
    //this line is necessary to make JS and php communicate with json
    //header("Content-type: text/javascript");
    //$searchQuery = "facebook";

    $searchQuery = $_GET['q'];
    $googleUrl='http://www.google.com/search?q='.$searchQuery;
    $googleSource = @file_get_contents($googleUrl);
    $bingUrl = 'http://www.bing.com/search?q=' .$searchQuery.'&first=1';
    $bingSource = @file_get_contents($bingUrl);
    $bingGoogleArray = array($bingSource,$googleSource);
    echo json_encode($bingGoogleArray);
    //echo $googleSource;
?>
```

And this is the html page :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Ajax And Jquery</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script>
        function ajaxTest() {
            //var string = "<html><body><b>Hello World</b></body></html>";
            //$('#test').html(string);
            $.ajax({url:"testJqueryAjax.php?q=facebook" , success: function(result){
                $('h1').empty();
                //var data = JSON.parse(result);
                var data = $.parseJSON(result);
                $('p').html(data[1]);   
                //alert(data[1]);
            }});
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="search" style="height:15%;">
            <button onClick="ajaxTest()">Submit</button>
        <h1>Loading</h1>
    </div>


    <p></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

The role of this little web application it that the php script search a keyword on google and bing and the return a json encoded array that contains the html source of the bing search page and google page.

On the html page i parse the json_encoded array that I received from the php script and i copy data[i] into a html tag .

The problem is when I copy `data[0]` that contains Bing search page into html tag the result appears but when I copy `data[1]` that contains Google search page into html tag nothing appears ! :(

You may say the `$googleSource` is empty but when I send from the php script $googleSource alone it works !

Comment: Questions like this are asked 10 times a day. Just watch the main page for a few minutes!

Comment: Done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($bingGoogleArray)` on the server? As well, note that scraping search results like this is a violation of Google's ToS.

Comment: It seems that you didn't understood me , the problem is when i send $googleSource alone it can be displayed in html . But if i send $googleSource and $bingSource in json encoded array only $bingSource can be displayed .

Comment: @Tomáš Zato i searched but the answer for my question don't exist .

Answer (score 0):

i checked your source, and for me $googleSource is null. the error is:  `json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument`

so try with this line:

```
$googleSource = utf8_encode(@file_get_contents($googleUrl));
```